# Are Java2D and Swing examples of Good Use of OOP?

Tags: java, swing, oop, inheritance

**Overusing Inheritance ?**

Java Swing and Java2D rely a lot on inheritance. Most people have told me I should avoid inheritance as much as possible and only use it when necessary. So is the extensive use of Inheritance in Java2D and Java Swing justified?

**Adapter Pattern**

I have heard a lot of praise for the adapter pattern, and I've heard a lot of criticism. What I gathered from all that, though, is that the adapter pattern is only considered good design if used at the right place. Irrelevant use of the adapter pattern causes people reading your code to scowl. Is the adapter pattern correctly and relevantly used in the two Java APIs?

**Singletons**

Both APIs also tend to use a considerable number of Singletons. Is this good?

**The Question**

So, Is The Java2D Api and Java Swing a good example of an Object Oriented Programming Interface?  Should I use their techniques in my code?

Comment: Java has no technique other than inheritance, so I fail to see how any Java API can *not* overuse it.

Comment: The whole of Java API uses Inheritance extensively not just swing and java2d. and there is no overuse there.

Comment: @DeadMG: Even Java offers more design tools than just inheritance. What about delegation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no certainty on this, but I can offer some thought:

- inheritance: suppose you preffered to use interfaces and composition instead of reuse-by-inheritance in Swing, then you would need to do an awful lot of forwarding (`Component` and `JComponent` have dozens of methods)
- adapter pattern: see above
- singletons: they are appropriate to model parts of a system which are genuinely unique (I would agree that `java.awt.Desktop` could be implemented as a singleton -- even though it uses a factory method)
- overall design: you might opt to judge things by results -- Swing is robust, extensible, and widely used.

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine who works with Swing complains constantly that it is an abstract morass. Determining the behavior of an object at run-time involves piecing together a bizarre collage of inherited functionality. From what I've seen of it I'm inclined to agree.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that GUI programming is a bizarre collage of requirements and situations?  Yes, Swing is complicated, but on the other hand I can insert my functionality where I want to, my Swing GUIs are less constrained by what the framework thought would be a good idea for its event model, or its table filtering, or whatever.

Answer (score -1):

> Inheritance is a useful programming concept, but it is easy to use
>   inappropriately.
>
> Inheritance is a good choice when:
>
> 1. Your inheritance hierarchy represents an "is-a" relationship and not a "has-a" relationship.
> 2. You can reuse code from the base classes.
> 3. You need to apply the same class and methods to different data
>      types.
> 4. The class hierarchy is reasonably shallow, and other developers are
>      not likely to add many more levels.
> 5. You want to make global changes to derived classes by changing a
>      base class.

A microsoft article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27db6csx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and another good one [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-1998/jw-11-techniques.html)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. It appears to be a stock answer about inheritance.